# Magnitude of a complex number

Tags: complex-numbers

How might we show that $\Big|{b^2+d^2-a^2-c^2+i2ab+i2cd\over a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+2}\Big|\le 1$ if we are given that $ad-bc=1$ and $a,b,c,d$ are real?

Comment: @WillieWong: thank you!!!

Comment: sorry for not posting it originally as an answer. I got lazy at first, but then decided to [practice what I preach](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/3220/1543).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write $z = (ia + b)$ and $w = (ic + d)$, the denominator is $z^2 + w^2$ and the numerator is $|z|^2 + |w|^2 + 2$. Then you can use the triangle inequality.